# Can you sort the output of SHOW COLUMNS or DESC?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting

Is it possible to (easily) sort the output of the SHOW COLUMNS or DESC MySQL Command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can sort the table names using `order by` but you have to `select` the column names from the `information_schema` below is the column names in `alphabetical` order

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'table_name' ORDER BY column_name
```